# How do I move my Rect that has text across the screen?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a project where I want to move this text box that I made from the left to the right.  I have multiple of these text boxes, and I wanted to do that right after one another.

`text1_rect = text1.get_rect(center = (window_width/2, window_height*.25))` : This is the current location of the text, but I was looking at the rect.move method to do this.

`window.blit(text1, text1_rect)` : This is how I `blit` the text onto the screen when the program first starts up.

I don't require a direct answer, but maybe just some tips or a nudge in the right direction on how to add a little movement to my text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `text1_rect` before the application loop and change the position of the rectangle in the application loop

If you want to move the text form from the left to the center of the window, you need to set the start position outside the window and move the text until it is in the center.

Use [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) to control the frames per second and thus the game speed.

The method [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object, delays the game in that way, that every iteration of the loop consumes the same period of time. See [`pygame.time.Clock.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick):

> This method should be called once per frame.

That means that the loop:

> ```py
> clock = pygame.time.Clock()
> run = True
> while run:
>    clock.tick(60)
> ```

runs 60 times per second.

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# initial position is outside the window
text1_rect = text1.get_rect(midright = (0, window_height*.25))

# [...]

while run:
    clock.tick(60)

    # [...]

    window.blit(text1, text1_rect)
   
    # move the text to the center
    if text1_rect.centerx < window_width // 2: 
        text1_rect.x += 1

    # [...]
```